# psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool, exceção OperationalError demora para ser lançada

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, driver

Fiz um teste, desliguei o servidor e chamei o método `psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool`, o método fica esperando uma resposta por um tempo muito longo, mais ou menos um minuto, só então ele levanta a exceção `OperationalError`.
Isso é normal? Tem como diminuir esse tempo de espera?

```
>>>import psycopg2, psycopg2.pool
>>> a=psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(1, 2, host = 'ip-do-server', user = 'postgres', password = 'postgres', database = 'nomebanco', port = 5432)
```

Comment: Poste o código responsável por esta rotina, assim fica melhor para a comunidade te ajudar, também sugiro que faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender mais sobre o site.

Comment: O código é simples:
>>>import psycopg2, psycopg2.pool
>>> a=psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(1, 2, host = 'ip-do-server', user = 'postgres', password = 'postgres', database = 'nomebanco', port = 5432)
.
.
.
Só depois de quase um minuto é que a exceção é lançada:

psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
 Is the server running on host "192.168.56.2" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Clique no botão 'editar' e adicione o código a pergunta.

Comment: Segue no ubuntupaste http://paste.ubuntu.com/14597266/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o [parâmetro `connect_timeout`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) em segundos:

```
psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool (
    1, 2,
    host = 'ip-do-server',
    user = 'postgres',
    password = 'postgres',
    database = 'nomebanco',
    port = 5432,
    connect_timeout = 15
)
```

Os parâmetros da [classe `SimpleConnectionPool`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/pool.html) são passados para a [função `connect`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect):

> New minconn connections are created automatically. The pool will support a maximum of about maxconn connections. *args and **kwargs are passed to the connect() function.

Que por sua vez remete para a libpq:

> The connection parameters can be specified either as a libpq connection string using the dsn parameter or using a set of keyword arguments

Comment: Ummmmmm. Não sabia da existência desse parâmetro. A documentação não mensiona, cita apenas a nomenclatura class psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(minconn, maxconn, *args, **kwargs)

Se a documentação não menciona como faço para saber quais os parâmetros?

Vi que você linkou a doc da libpq. Acho que a doc do psycopg deveria mencionar esses parâmetros, senão a coisa fica meio complicada, consultar na doc da libpq o que deveria estar da doc do psycopg2

Comment: @Matheus: Veja a atualização da resposta.